# How to perform `ALL` search across combination of multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I've got a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "title": "Dilemma: What's for lunch?",
  "description": "The age old question of what's for lunch has surfaced again."
  "tags": [
    { "title": "important" },
    { "title": "decision" }
  }
}
```

I want this document returned when I search for `dilemma AND question AND decision` (note that the search terms and the fields they exist in are mutually exclusive in this example.) If any of the provided terms don't exist in any of the fields, this document shouldn't be returned (so if I searched for `dilemma AND question AND decision AND foobar` nothing would be returned.)

I've tried using `bool` queries with various combinations of `must` and `should`, and `match` clauses with `operator: and`, but nothing has worked so far.

My question is: can this be done at query time? Or do I need to combine `title`, `description` and `tags.title` into a new field (say `keywords`) at index time (if so, how?)

Comment: If i understand everything correctly, you need to produce bool query with several `must` branches (one for every AND'ed term), each of which would consist of another bool query with three shoulds - for title, description and tags.title and minimum_should_match = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query itself can be generated from it's description: you need to find a document that satisfies match for every term, where match is treated as `title`, `description` or `tags.title` containing that term. So for each term you just need a bool query with three `should` clauses (one for each field), nested as one of subqueries under `must` bool clause:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "title": "important"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "description": "important"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "tags.title": "important"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query contains only one term (because otherwise it would be too huge for easy understanding), but expanding is as easy as adding new bool queries under `must` array. Please also note that you may want to substitute the `term` query with something less strict.

Here's the ruby code i used for query generation:

```
require 'json'

terms = %w[important dilemma decision]

clauses = terms.map do |term|
  {
    bool: {
      should: %w[title description tags.title].map do |field|
        {
          term: {
            field => term
          }
        }
      end
    }
  }
end

query = {
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: clauses
    }
  }
}

puts JSON.pretty_generate(query)
```

Comment: This is great, but there's a problem: it'll match records if you pass `foobar`, even though none of those fields contain that term. (I'm using `match` instead of `term`.)

Comment: @StevenMercatante i can't reproduce on 5.5.2 (created a query that should match foobar only and it didn't pass). My guess at this point is that you are running query against more sophisticated data set and constructed query does match terms in document (or you are trying to match a phrase, and that's a little bit different story for match). May i ask you to specify your ES version and provide a reproducible example that fails?

Comment: I was using `match` with the default `or` operator. Switching to `and` gave me the desired results. Thanks for your help!